# android automotive compatibility

Tags: android, android-automotive

I have developed an media app for android phone. I have to make that app compatible for android automotive (not auto). Can anyone please explain the steps required for this. I have checked the Android AOSP [site](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/), and my app does not require the car or the other apis mentioned on that site. (I don't know if those are required to make the app compatible)

Comment: There's now an Android Automotive emulator that you can try your app on, if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there are any rules or constraints for implementation for Android Automotive provided yet.

There is a list of criteria for designing apps for Android Auto:

https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/auto-app-quality

I would assume that for Android Automotive some of the criteria will be also applied as they concern UI and functionality from the driver's perspective.

**NOTE:** I think some guidelines might be defined soon since Google is finally going to support Android Automotive in Android Studio (similarly as they did for Auto).

Answer (score -1):

For design guidelines, please refer to g.co/automotive-design 
For technical/testing guidelines, please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/
For playstore review / quality guidelines, they are not published yet